# Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\left(nz_1+(n-1)z_2+\cdots+2z_{n-1}+z_n\right)=z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $(z_{n})$ be a sequence of complex numbers converging to $z_0$. Show that
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\left(nz_1 + (n-1)z_2 + \cdots + 2z_{n-1} + z_n\right) = z_0$$

I try this using

$$a_{n} = \frac{2}{n(n+1)}\left(nz_1 + (n-1)z_2 +...+2z_{n-1}+ z_n\right) - z_{0}$$

and trying to demostrated that $\lim a_n = 0 $ but I'm stuck in a triangular inequality. How can I prove this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see
$$\frac{2}{n(n+1)}( nz_1+...+z_n) =\frac{2}{n(n+1)}(n+1)(z_1+z_2+...+z_n) -\frac{2}{n(n+1)}(z_1+2z_2+...+nz_n) $$
I think it's now clear for you to do the rest.

**Update**
Hm, I think I should put in a more clear representation.
So if you define $b_n=z_n-z_0$, you can see that $\lim |b_n| =0$ and
$$\| \frac{2}{n(n+1)}( nz_1+...+z_n) -z_0 \| \le 2\frac{ |b_1|+...+|b_n|}{n}+ \frac{ |b_1|+...+n|b_n|}{1+...+n}$$
From which you can apply Cesaro's theorem.

Comment: Thanks for tyour help, i could finish the problem using your hint